# Generate PDF file of page content in OutSystems

Tags: outsystems

I am using OutSystems Platform, and I want to generate a PDF file of page content in OutSystems.

I searched a lot on Google and got some extensions to generate PDF in OutSystems, but they are not working.

Please help me how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the Html2PdfConverter extension which can be downloaded through the OutSystems Forge.

It uses the wkhtmltopdf.exe tool to convert your html page to a pdf file.

I have answered the same question in another post. Check the following link : [Html2PdfExample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37623315/2235067)

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the tip @dur.