# Html2PdfConverter Sample Conversion

Tags: outsystems

I am new to Outsystems and having a page where each users signs an agreement. Every time the agreement is signed it needs to be converted in to pdf and attached in to email and sent. I have set up all the email part, for converting the page in to PDF I have installed the extension. But I am I am not sure how to proceed. Can I have any sample appliccation where it is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to configure the HTML2PDFConverter extension. To do that, open the extension through your web browser, and follow the instructions on the "installation instructions" page.

After completing the configuring, the "administration" page should look something like this.

[image: Html2PdfConfigurations]